# Insert statement with autoincrement parameter

Tags: sql, select, insert, db2

I am trying to insert data into a table using an insert statement with the results from a select statement in DB2.

I am encountering an issue with the primary key which needs to be autoincremented from a specific value ex: from 100 upgoing and I should tell the statement from what value it should increment, but it does not work.

The insert statement looks something like this:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4 ,col5)
    select par1, par2, par3, par4, par5 from table2;
```

Using this statement it imports the primary key automatically, which is wrong because it should be generated/autoincremented from a specific value.

I tried to create a Variable and to set it as par1 like this var1=var1+1 but it does not work.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please tell what you're trying to achieve business-wise? IMO primary key is just a number of insignificant (as long as unique) value and building ANY logic around it's value is a very serious mistake.

Comment: I would like to create a temporary table where I can import data and then the data from this table should be imported into another table, however in the second table the primary key starts from 10000. Because of this value, I have to set the primary key for the rows starting with 10001, then for the second row 10002 and so on. Just trying to move data from a temporary table into another table, but the primary key is missing from the temporary table and the second table needs it.

Comment: It will be auto generated if you omit it in insert statement, why do you need any specific value?

Comment: It does not auto generated because the table was not created with this functionality in mind. Therefor I have to create it manually. It give an error Null not allowed if I omit the primary key.

Comment: Have you looked into creating a sequence with a specific start value? It can be incremented as part of the read operation. So you could include it in the SELECT statement

Comment: I used, "Create Sequence START WITH 1" and it works, but instead of 1 I need a select statement and selects are not allowed there next to START WITH.

Answer (score 0):

You can first set the default value (if its one time load) or some max value based on some other logic like SELECT MAX(col).

```
set initval = 100;
```

Then you can use ROW_NUMBER() function to generate a running sequence. In the order include the columns that will identify the primary keys.

```
insert into table1 (genkeycol, col1, col2, col3, col4 ,col5)
select initval + row_number() over(order by par1, par2) as genkeycol
par1, par2, par3, par4, par5 from table2;
```

Ideally, you should use GENERATED column so that you don't have to worry about this logic. I wouldn't recommend using sequence for large volume insert.